# cURL Upload Speed

Tags: php, performance, curl, upload

I was wondering why it takes so long for cURL to upload.

I debugged it and got this...

```
[url] =>  [url] => http://srv644.ryushare.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_id=26182539075&js_on=1&utype=reg&upload_type=file  
[content_type] => text/html
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 153
[request_size] => 454
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 28.423
[namelookup_time] => 0.062
[connect_time] => 0.062
[pretransfer_time] => 0.062
[size_upload] => 104858196
[size_download] => 305
[speed_download] => 10
[speed_upload] => 3689202
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 104858196
[starttransfer_time] => 0.078
[redirect_time] => 0
```

From what i understand, the transfer is due to the actual file itself (28.8 seconds in total). But this doesn't make sense because...
A) Server speed upload is 20mb/sec tested in browser (Same file same everything)
B) The Server Upload speed listed there is 3mb/sec

Is there any reason why there would be such a big difference in speed?

Comment: you might try pinging & a traceroute the url and sharing the results as this could possibly shed some light on network issues.

Comment: Updated with URL. URL and traceroute of URL is perfectly normal. The url i'm posting to does not have any problem....

Comment: Anybody know the solution? I've tested it with all other servers...(Googling PHP Windows 2008 Curl Upload Slow High Bandwidth) seems to give a similiar problem but no solution...